# jQuery wait for animation by querying animation queue?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I know the official way to wait for an animation is a callback sent to the animation function.  Is it still possible to somehow query the animation queue, performing a wait loop (with a [watchdog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer)) outside the animation call?

## Example (and a concrete problem)

We are using [jQuery lightbox 0.5](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) *and have moved the close button and added some info content*.
The box renders correct except in IE8, where the bottom items are positioned too far up until the page is resized or a mouse over occurs.

It seems that IE needs to wait between animations in order to succeed properly.
I would like to fix this problem **without changing the flow of the code**. Is it possible?

This is from jQuery lightbox:

```
/**
* Show the prepared image
*
*/
function _show_image() {
    $('#lightbox-loading').hide();
    $('#lightbox-image').fadeIn(function () {
        _show_image_data();
        _set_navigation();
    });
    _preload_neighbor_images();
};
/**
* Show the image information
*
*/
function _show_image_data() {
    $('#lightbox-container-image-data-box').slideDown('fast');
```

If I change it like this, it works fine in IE8:

```
/**
* Show the prepared image
*
*/
function _show_image() {
    $('#lightbox-loading').hide();
    $('#lightbox-image').fadeIn(function () {
        _show_image_data();
    });
    _preload_neighbor_images();
};
/**
* Show the image information
*
*/
function _show_image_data() {
    $('#lightbox-container-image-data-box').slideDown('fast', function () {
        _set_navigation();
    });
```

**Can I wait for the animation queue for a certain element?**

Pseudo code:

```
/**
* Show the prepared image
*
*/
function _show_image() {
    $('#lightbox-loading').hide();
    $('#lightbox-image').fadeIn(function () {
        _show_image_data();
        var timeout = 500;
        $('#lightbox-container-image-data-box').waitForAnimation(timeout);
        _set_navigation();
    });
    _preload_neighbor_images();
};
/**
* Show the image information
*
*/
function _show_image_data() {
    $('#lightbox-container-image-data-box').slideDown('fast');
```

Comment: Have a look at [jQuery.fn.queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `queue` your own function into the effects (fx) queue, and even `delay` them if you want. Just make sure you're applying it to the exact same element as lightbox.

```
$('#lightbox-image').delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
   // your code here

   if (next) next(); 
});
```